# Как стилизировать окно разрешения на web-камеру?

Tags: jquery, css3

Как можно стилизировать это окно.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Может можно  его скрыть и имитировать события по нажатию на другой элемент?

Comment: Стилизовать - никак. Разве создать свой.

Comment: Вообще никак, если создать свой, то для разрешения все равно этот вылезет. Имитировать тоже никак, браузер защищает пользователей от таких как вы ;)

Comment: Видел на просторах интернета сайт, по работе с камерой. Там стандартное окно не показывалось. А показывалось кастомное, пользовательское окно. А как создать своё?

Comment: Возможно, вы попутали с Flash-окном, потому что никак.